# JavaFX - left border on Button without moving its text or resizing it

Tags: java, css, button, javafx

I want to create a `Button`. At the start it has no border, just a background-color. So I set the following CSS attributes:

```
.button, .toggle-button {
  -fx-background-color: #373e48;
  -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
```

When the `Button` is pressed / selected, a border on the left side should appear, so I added this:

```
.button:pressed, .toggle-button:selected {
  -fx-border-color: #ee543a;
  -fx-border-width: 0 0 0 2px;
}
```

The problem with that is that everytime the border is shown, the `Button` gets a little bit wider.

I also tried to set the alignment to `center-right` and add a minimum width, but if the `Button` gets bigger, it doesn't work anymore like that. And it does actually not look like I want it to.

So, how can I do that without this behavior? Preferably with the text aligned to the center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this simply in CSS using `-fx-background-insets` attribute:

```
.button, .toggle-button {
  -fx-background-color: #373e48;
  -fx-background-radius: 0;
  -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.button:pressed, .toggle-button:selected {
  -fx-background-color: #ee543a, #373e48;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 0 2;
}
```

[image]

Te second selector creates two layers of the two colors. The original background color gets a 2 pixel inset on the left side, therefore the underlying layer (color of the "border") will be shown as a 2 pixel border on the left.

A closer look on this selector: `-fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 0 2;` the first (underlying) background color has no insets. The color on the top has 2 pixel inset on the left, as the four number means `top, right, bottom, left`.

**Note:** Text alignment is unnecessary, as the default text alignment for a `Button` or a `ToggleButton` is center, but in any case you can align the text also from CSS:

```
.button, .toggle-button {
    -fx-text-alignment: center; //* or left, right, justify  *//
}
```